# vue js cannot use custom axios settings

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using axios in my cue project and trying to set some custom default setting to use it.

So i made a axios.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8081'

export default axios.create({
  baseUrl: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
  }
})
```

then i mounted it in here /components/axios/index.js using my axios

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

import axios from './axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

In this way i should have set globally axios with my settings right?

So in my Login.vue component file i call this method

```
login() {
      this.$http
        .post("/oauth/token", {
          username: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          client_id: "test",
          client_secret: "test",
          grant_type: "password"
        },
        )
        .then(request => this.loginSuccessful(request))
        .catch(() => this.loginFailed());
    }
```

but `$http` does not have my custom settings but axios generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I run into the same issue and found that baseURL is case-sensitive.

Hence `baseUrl` should be `baseURL` and everything will work fine.

Here is `axios` [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig) for the creating instance.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

> Here is working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5km290w9x4)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

good luck to find an answer. 
But are you sure to use correctly axios ?
I see this.$http.post is for the normal request without axios and on npm VueAxios don't use this.

I can recommend you this link
https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html